# Why is that I can import one npm package and not the other (Webpack setup)?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm importing two libraries in the exact same way ([lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) and [aframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe)):

[image]

[image]

The first one exports successfully:

```
error  no-unused-vars  "_" is defined but never used
E:\alex\istaging-viewer\src\components\Pano\PanoList.vue:10:8
import _ from 'lodash'
```

(Lodash is defined.)

For the second one, Webpack (or npm?) tells me there's no file or directory with that name:

```
ERROR in ./~/aframe/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./package in E:\alex\istaging-viewer\node_modules\aframe
 @ ./~/aframe/index.js 3:10-30

ERROR in ./~/aframe/~/aframe-core/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../package in E:\alex\istaging-viewer\node_modules\aframe\node_modules\aframe-core\src
 @ ./~/aframe/~/aframe-core/src/index.js 16:10-31

ERROR in ./~/aframe/elements/templates/index.html
Module parse failed: E:\alex\istaging-viewer\node_modules\aframe\elements\templates\index.html Line 1: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <!doctype html>
| <meta charset="utf-8">
|
 @ ./~/aframe/elements/index.js 7:0-33
```

Why is this?

**NOTE: This is my Webpack setup:**

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/static'),
    publicPath: '/static/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue', 'styl'],
    alias: {
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
    }
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash:7]'
        }
      },

      { test: /\.styl$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader' },

      { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,  loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
      { test: /\.eot$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
      { test: /\.svg$/,    loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  },
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to error message and aframe [source code](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/2c45a7b6c572523f89ff39270a3e193bcd865b2e/elements/index.js) you should specify appropriate loader for html files in your webpack config.
Not shure, but this can be suitable - https://github.com/webpack/html-loader or you can try `url-loader`

```
   loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      ... skipped ...
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
```